# Event listener issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm learning event listeners but i cant get to make it add a line of text when clicking an image
my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Cat Clicker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
    <script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <img alt= "Black Cat" src= "img/tesla-cat.jpg" class="gatito">
    <p class="clicks"> </p>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the javascript file:

```
$(".gatito").click(function() {
    var text = "";
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i<0; i++) {
    text += ("The kitten has been clicked " + i + "times");

}

$(".clicks").innerHTML= text;

}

);
```

a helping hand?

Comment: Remove the backtick before `$(".gatito").click` (and after the end), else the whole code will be interpreted as an unused string, rather than actual code

Comment: jQuery objects don't have a `innerHTML` property. Use the `.text` method: http://api.jquery.com/text/  . But besides that, your loop never runs because `i < 0` is always false.

Comment: `i` is equal to zero and loop for while`i<0` ? So do not loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly check the code. Your `for` loop never runs as the terminating condition is always false i.e. `i < 0` is always false.

```
$(".gatito").click(function(){
    var text = "";
    var i;
    var countLimit = 5;//some value greater than 0
    for (i = 0; i < countLimit; i++) {
      text += ("The kitten has been clicked " + i + "times");
    }
    $(".clicks").text(text);
 }

);
```